# How to create two section arrange by horizontal at UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ios13, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I want to arrange UICollectionView cell like this:
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAc9v.jpg)

but, i really got like this:
[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRCV5.jpg)

What should I do to arrange cell layout as shown in picture 1?

```
private func twoRowLayout() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                          heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 1, leading: 1, bottom: 1, trailing: 1)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5),
                                           heightDimension: .absolute(40))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 2)

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 2, leading: 15, bottom: 2, trailing: 10)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .none
    
    let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .absolute(40))
    let headerItem = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .topLeading)
    section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [headerItem]
    
    return section
}
```

Have any idea?